# Graphviz - how to position a subgraph's label at bottom?

Tags: graphviz, dot, subgraph

In graphviz, by default a subgraph's label is placed at the top, like this:

[image: h]

How do I place the label at the bottom instead please.

I've tried the 'labeljust' attribute however the only options for this are l,r,c for left, right and centre...
https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html

Anyone know if there's a similar attribute to position the label at bottom. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`labelloc`](http://martin-loetzsch.de/S-DOT/labelloc.html):

```
graph [labelloc=b]
```

[image]